# Does MVC pattern implement common tasks of web framework?

Tags: go, model-view-controller, design-patterns, httpbackend, servemux

The common tasks of web application framework(ex: Django or Laravel or .NET or beego):

```
request / response abstraction 
session state 
user authentication & authorisation 
page templating 
URL mapping 
DB access 
security 
caching
```

---

MVC design pattern implement above common tasks,  as shown below:

1. **URL mapping** is handled by **Controller** component of MVC. Controller routes requests to **handlers**. Ex: `http.ServeMux` is the controller from GOLang [package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux)
2. **request / response abstraction**  is performed by *Controller* by registering  the **handlers**, written by web developer, as shown below:

   ```
   sm := http.NewServeMux()     // in GoLang

   sm.Handle("/", productHandler)
   ```
3. **session state** is handled by the **handler** code written by web developer
4. **Page templating** is handled by templating engine(view component) of MVC
5. **user authentication & authorisation** is handled by the **handler** code written by web developer
6. **DB access** is handled by **model** component of MVC.
7. **security**  and **caching** is handled by **handler** code written by web developer

---

Is this the right understanding on MVC design pattern to implement common tasks of web application  framework?

Comment: no ... the notion of MVC predates creation of the web

Comment: @ScottStensland  yes, but.... does the seven points mentioned in the query, holds good?

Comment: the point of using any of the many Design Patterns is any given pattern only does one crisp focused job ... so no a design pattern is not an app framework

Comment: "Is this the right understanding on MVC design pattern...?" There is no "right understanding" of something so broad as MVC, which has no single definition.

Answer (score 1):

There are many definitions of the MVC pattern. It was evolving over time and it was used differently in different frameworks and contexts.
When it was invented, there was no HTTP protocol and the request/response part wasn't present. There were some other ways in which the user request was handled. With time, new template engines were invented and HTTP becomes dominant protocol on the web.

MVC is considered to be a pure presentation pattern since it mainly orchestrates views and model(whatever model is representing). Also, one of the main reasons why MVC is invented is separation of concern. It is important to keep it clean, short and to let other layers take care of logic.

The common task of the web application framework is to serve as IoC container (Inversion of control) and let its component worry about specific responsibilities. So if it is a web framework, it will probably have session, cookie, MVC... components.

1. Controller methods are just an implementation of HTTP interface. URL Mapping can be considered as an argument to controller method.
2. Request/response are handled by web component (servlet in Java)
3. Session state is handled by session component and can be configured by developer e.g. session expire time or session cookie type or even session type (database, in memory)
4. Correct
5. Usually, there is a proven auth component in the framework, but it can be written manually (not recommended)
6. DB access is handled by a persistence layer like JDBC in Java. Model in MVC is responsible for data that should be presented on the screen or submitted by the user.
7. Same as 5